# Chrome Binary Issue in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am facing a problem when i tried to execute a selenium code in my asp.net Application.
I am getting this error

```
unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
```

But it's running fine in Local machine.The problem is happening only in the server.
What should i do now!

Comment: Sounds like Chrome isn't installed on your CI/CD platform?  What does "the server" refer to?

Comment: No it's already installed.

Comment: what does "the server" refer to ?  Is it Jenkins? TeamCity? TFS?

Comment: What options are you using for build?  It looks like server is using options x86 compatible and 64 bits.

Comment: is your chrome installed in the default location? if not, you need to set the chrome.exe path. ChromeOptions chromeOptions= new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setBinary("Yourpath\\Chrome.exe");

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);